# Update table periodically

Tags: php, mysql

I have access to a mysql database, but I can only read from it. I need a copy of one of the tables in a local DB, and I need it to update every 2 hours. 
What is the best/most efficient way of copying/updating periodically a table?

Should I make a plain php script that fetches and updates the data (my app is in php)? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You can use the standard MySQL Replication if bin-log is on and you can set the grants for the replication. Or you can use percona tool pt-table-sync. this tool can direct synchronize your tables or database, see : https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can only read from that DB, it means you can't create a trigger, or setup replication which would be most-efficient way.

Unless you are ready to pay high sum for systems like percona or TIBCO.
 PHP or other scripting language would be great solution, combined with cron job, or scheduled tasks on windows...

Since you mentioned PHP I would recommend searching for ready-made scripts, like this one:
https://github.com/mrjgreen/db-sync

Download the script, unpack at your server, and create a shell script which would look like this:

> db-sync [options] [--] <source> <target> <table>

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
db-sync --user root --password mypass 127.0.0.1 111.222.3.44 web.customers
```

name it **sync.sh**

And add crontab entry to run every 2hrs as you requested:

```
0 */2 * * *  /home/username/sync.sh
```

Just replace the /home/username with a path towards your sync.sh